# Problem when Running Yolov5s-segmentation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ros

I am a Ubuntu user to run Yolov5 with my ROS node.
At the beginnings, I used the code in yolov5s to detect object and provide x,y,z from Intel Realsense Camera D435. The program is running without any errors.

After I changed to yolov5s-seg for the segmentation task. The code predict.py still works but then I modified it into the code below:

```
import argparse
import os
import platform
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont
import torch
import numpy as np
import time
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import math

FILE = Path(__file__).resolve()
ROOT = FILE.parents[1]  # YOLOv5 root directory
if str(ROOT) not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(str(ROOT))  # add ROOT to PATH
ROOT = Path(os.path.relpath(ROOT, Path.cwd()))  # relative

from ultralytics.utils.plotting import Annotator, colors, save_one_box

from models.common import DetectMultiBackend
from utils.dataloaders import IMG_FORMATS, VID_FORMATS, LoadImages, LoadScreenshots, LoadStreams
from utils.general import (LOGGER, Profile, check_file, check_img_size, check_imshow, check_requirements, colorstr, cv2,
                           increment_path, non_max_suppression, print_args, scale_boxes, scale_segments,
                           strip_optimizer)
from utils.segment.general import masks2segments, process_mask, process_mask_native
from utils.torch_utils import select_device, smart_inference_mode

from math import atan2, cos, sin, sqrt, pi, asin, acos

def drawAxis(img, p_, q_, colour, scale):
    p = list(p_)
    q = list(q_)

    angle = atan2(p[1] - q[1], p[0] - q[0])  # angle in radians
    hypotenuse = sqrt((p[1] - q[1]) * (p[1] - q[1]) + (p[0] - q[0]) * (p[0] - q[0]))
    # Here we lengthen the arrow by a factor of scale
    q[0] = p[0] - scale * hypotenuse * cos(angle)
    q[1] = p[1] - scale * hypotenuse * sin(angle)
    cv2.line(img, (int(p[0]), int(p[1])), (int(q[0]), int(q[1])), colour, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    # create the arrow hooks
    p[0] = q[0] + 9 * cos(angle + pi / 4)
    p[1] = q[1] + 9 * sin(angle + pi / 4)
    cv2.line(img, (int(p[0]), int(p[1])), (int(q[0]), int(q[1])), colour, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    p[0] = q[0] + 9 * cos(angle - pi / 4)
    p[1] = q[1] + 9 * sin(angle - pi / 4)
    cv2.line(img, (int(p[0]), int(p[1])), (int(q[0]), int(q[1])), colour, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

def get_frame_stream():
    cfg = rs.config() #ok
    cfg.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 60) #ok
    cfg.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 60) #ok

    pipe = rs.pipeline()
    profile = pipe.start(cfg)

    #pipe.start(cfg)
    align_to = rs.stream.color
    align = rs.align(align_to)

    frames = pipe.wait_for_frames()
    aligned_frames = align.process(frames)
    depth_frame = aligned_frames.get_depth_frame()
    color_frame = aligned_frames.get_color_frame()
    depth_frame.get_height()

    if not depth_frame or not color_frame:
        # If there is no frame, probably camera not connected, return False
        print(
            "Error, impossible to get the frame, make sure that the Intel Realsense camera is correctly connected")
        return None, None

        # Apply filter to fill the Holes in the depth image
    color_intrin = color_frame.profile.as_video_stream_profile().intrinsics

    spatial = rs.spatial_filter()
    spatial.set_option(rs.option.holes_fill, 3)
    filtered_depth = spatial.process(depth_frame)

    hole_filling = rs.hole_filling_filter()
    filled_depth = hole_filling.process(filtered_depth)

    # Create colormap to show the depth of the Objects
    colorizer = rs.colorizer()
    depth_colormap = np.asanyarray(colorizer.colorize(filled_depth).get_data())

    # Convert images to numpy arrays
    # distance = depth_frame.get_distance(int(50),int(50))
    # print("distance", distance)
    depth_image = np.asanyarray(filled_depth.get_data())
    color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

    # cv2.imshow("Colormap", depth_colormap)
    # cv2.imshow("depth img", depth_image)

    return True, frames, color_image, depth_image, color_frame, depth_frame, color_intrin


def run(
    weights=ROOT / 'yolov5s-seg.pt',  # model.pt path(s)
    source=ROOT / 'data/images',  # file/dir/URL/glob/screen/0(webcam)
    data=ROOT / 'data/coco128-seg.yaml',  # dataset.yaml path
    imgsz=(640, 640),  # inference size (height, width)
    conf_thres=0.25,  # confidence threshold
    iou_thres=0.45,  # NMS IOU threshold
    max_det=1000,  # maximum detections per image
    device='',  # cuda device, i.e. 0 or 0,1,2,3 or cpu
    view_img=False,  # show results
    save_txt=False,  # save results to *.txt
    save_conf=False,  # save confidences in --save-txt labels
    save_crop=False,  # save cropped prediction boxes
    nosave=False,  # do not save images/videos
    classes=None,  # filter by class: --class 0, or --class 0 2 3
    agnostic_nms=False,  # class-agnostic NMS
    augment=False,  # augmented inference
    visualize=False,  # visualize features
    update=False,  # update all models
    project=ROOT / 'runs/predict-seg',  # save results to project/name
    name='exp',  # save results to project/name
    exist_ok=False,  # existing project/name ok, do not increment
    line_thickness=3,  # bounding box thickness (pixels)
    hide_labels=False,  # hide labels
    hide_conf=False,  # hide confidences
    half=False,  # use FP16 half-precision inference
    dnn=False,  # use OpenCV DNN for ONNX inference
    vid_stride=1,  # video frame-rate stride
    retina_masks=False,

):
    source = str(source)
    save_img = not nosave and not source.endswith('.txt')  # save inference images
    is_file = Path(source).suffix[1:] in (IMG_FORMATS + VID_FORMATS)
    is_url = source.lower().startswith(('rtsp://', 'rtmp://', 'http://', 'https://'))
    webcam = source.isnumeric() or source.endswith('.streams') or (is_url and not is_file)
    screenshot = source.lower().startswith('screen')
    if is_url and is_file:
        source = check_file(source)  # download

    # Directories
    save_dir = increment_path(Path(project) / name, exist_ok=exist_ok)  # increment run
    (save_dir / 'labels' if save_txt else save_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # make dir

    # Load model
    device = select_device(device)
    model = DetectMultiBackend(weights, device=device, dnn=dnn, data=data, fp16=half)
    stride, names, pt = model.stride, model.names, model.pt
    imgsz = check_img_size(imgsz, s=stride)  # check image size

    # Dataloader
    bs = 1  # batch_size
    if webcam:
        view_img = check_imshow(warn=True)
        dataset = LoadStreams(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt, vid_stride=vid_stride)
        bs = len(dataset)
    elif screenshot:
        dataset = LoadScreenshots(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt)
    else:
        dataset = LoadImages(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt, vid_stride=vid_stride)
    vid_path, vid_writer = [None] * bs, [None] * bs

    # Run inference
    model.warmup(imgsz=(1 if pt else bs, 3, *imgsz))  # warmup
    seen, windows, dt = 0, [], (Profile(), Profile(), Profile())
    for path, im, im0s, vid_cap, s in dataset:
        with dt[0]:
            frame_img = vid_cap
            im = torch.from_numpy(im).to(model.device)
            im = im.half() if model.fp16 else im.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
            imnew = im.half() if model.fp16 else im.int()  # uint8 to fp16/32
            im /= 255  # 0 - 255 to 0.0 - 1.0
            if len(im.shape) == 3:
                im = im[None]  # expand for batch dim

        # Inference
        with dt[1]:
            visualize = increment_path(save_dir / Path(path).stem, mkdir=True) if visualize else False
            pred, proto = model(im, augment=augment, visualize=visualize)[:2]

        # NMS
        with dt[2]:
            pred = non_max_suppression(pred, conf_thres, iou_thres, classes, agnostic_nms, max_det=max_det, nm=32)

        # Second-stage classifier (optional)
        # pred = utils.general.apply_classifier(pred, classifier_model, im, im0s)

        # Process predictions
        for i, det in enumerate(pred):  # per image
            seen += 1
            p, im0, frame = path[i], im0s[i].copy(), dataset.count
            s += f'{i}: '

            p = Path(p)  # to Path
            save_path = str(save_dir / p.name)  # im.jpg
            txt_path = str(save_dir / 'labels' / p.stem) + ('' if dataset.mode == 'image' else f'_{frame}')  # im.txt
            s += '%gx%g ' % im.shape[2:]  # print string
            annotator = Annotator(im0, line_width=line_thickness, example=str(names))
            if len(det):
                masks = process_mask(proto[i], det[:, 6:], det[:, :4], im.shape[2:], upsample=True)  # HWC
                #print(masks)
                det[:, :4] = scale_boxes(im.shape[2:], det[:, :4], im0.shape).round()  # rescale boxes to im0 size

                masks2 = process_mask(proto[i], det[:, 6:], det[:, :4], imnew.shape[2:], upsample=True)  # HWC
                #print(masks)
                det[:, :4] = scale_boxes(imnew.shape[2:], det[:, :4], im0.shape).round()  # rescale boxes to im0 size

                segments2 = [
                    scale_segments(im0.shape if retina_masks else imnew.shape[2:], x, im0.shape, normalize=False)
                    for x in reversed(masks2segments(masks))]
                #NumberOfElements = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
                #segments2_conver = np.array(segments2, dtype=np.int32)
                #print(segments2_conver)

                segments = [
                    scale_segments(im0.shape if retina_masks else im.shape[2:], x, im0.shape, normalize=True)
                    for x in reversed(masks2segments(masks))]
                #print(segments)

                # Print results
                for c in det[:, 5].unique():
                    n = (det[:, 5] == c).sum()  # detections per class
                    s += f"{n} {names[int(c)]}{'s' * (n > 1)}, "  # add to string
                    #print(n)
                # Mask plotting
                annotator.masks(
                    masks,
                    colors=[colors(x, True) for x in det[:, 5]],
                    im_gpu=torch.as_tensor(im0, dtype=torch.float16).to(device).permute(2, 0, 1).flip(0).contiguous() /
                    255 if retina_masks else im[i])

                ret, new_frame, bgr_image, depth_image, bgr_frame, depth_frame, color_intrin = get_frame_stream()
                # Write results
                for j, (*xyxy, conf, cls) in enumerate(reversed(det[:, :6])):
                    seg = segments[j].reshape(-1)  # (n,2) to (n*2)
                    #print(segments[j])
                    line = (cls, *seg, conf) if save_conf else (cls, *seg)  # label format
                    #with open(f'{txt_path}.txt', 'a') as f:
                        #f.write(('%g ' * len(line)).rstrip() % line + '\n')
                    c = int(cls)  # integer class
                    label = None if hide_labels else (names[c] if hide_conf else f'{names[c]} {conf:.2f}')

                    annotator.box_label(xyxy, label, color=colors(c, True))
                    box = xyxy
                    centerx, centery = int((int(box[0]) + int(box[2])) / 2), int((int(box[1]) + int(box[3])) / 2)
                    center_point = centerx, centery
                    #distance_mm = depth_image[centery, centerx]
                    #print(center_point)
                    #ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon(, segments2[j], outline=colors(c, True), width=3)
                    #cv2.circle(vid_cap,(segments2[j]), radius=1, color=(0,0,255), thickness=1)
                    im0 = annotator.result()
                    seg_point = np.array(segments2[j], dtype=np.int32)
                    #cv2.putText(im0, "{} mm".format(distance_mm), (centerx, centery - 10), 0, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    #center_point_XYZ = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(color_intrin, center_point, distance_mm)
                    #print(np.array(center_point_XYZ).astype(int))
                    print(center_point)
                    cv2.polylines(im0, [np.array(segments2[j], dtype=np.int32)], isClosed=True, color=(0,0,0), thickness=3)

                    "So this is the list of segmentation point segments2[j] "
                    #print([np.array(segments2[j], dtype=np.int32)])

                    "So we will move on to do the PCA for detecting vector X,Y for and object"
                    ""
                    # Perform PCA analysis
                    mean = np.empty((0))
                    mean, eigenvectors, eigenvalues = cv2.PCACompute2(np.array(segments2[j], dtype=np.float64), mean)
                    # Store the center of the object
                    cntr = (int(mean[0, 0]), int(mean[0, 1]))

                    # Draw the principal components
                    cv2.circle(im0, cntr, 3, (255, 0, 255), 2)
                    p1 = (cntr[0] + 0.02 * eigenvectors[0, 0] * eigenvalues[0, 0],
                          cntr[1] + 0.02 * eigenvectors[0, 1] * eigenvalues[0, 0])
                    p2 = (cntr[0] - 0.02 * eigenvectors[1, 0] * eigenvalues[1, 0],
                          cntr[1] - 0.02 * eigenvectors[1, 1] * eigenvalues[1, 0])
                    drawAxis(im0, cntr, p1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
                    drawAxis(im0, cntr, p2, (255, 255, 0), 5)
                    angle = atan2(eigenvectors[0, 1], eigenvectors[0, 0])  # orientation in radians
                    print(angle)

                    "So in This part we will try to extract the maximum, minimum of coordinates x,y"
                    "Remember that the highest point Y have the lowest value"
                    "Remember that the furthest point X have the highest value"

                    min_xy = np.min(seg_point, axis=0)
                    min_x , min_y = int(min_xy[0]), int(min_xy[1])

                    #index_ymin = np.where(seg_point == min_y)[0]
                    #list_ymin = index_ymin.tolist()
                    #cv2.circle(im0, index_ymin, 3, (255, 0, 0))
                    #index_xmin = np.where(seg_point == min_x)[0]
                    #cv2.circle(im0, index_xmin, 3, (255, 0, 0))

                    max_xy = np.max(seg_point, axis=0)
                    max_x, max_y = int(max_xy[0]), int(max_xy[1])

                    index_ymax = np.where(seg_point == max_y)[0]
                    index_xmax = np.where(seg_point == max_x)[0]
                    #cv2.circle(im0, index_ymax, 3, (255, 0, 0))q
                    #cv2.circle(im0, index_xmax, 3, (255, 0, 0))
                    #print(max)

                    center_point_updated = int((max_x+min_x)/2), int((max_y+min_y)/2)
                    cv2.circle(im0, center_point_updated, 3, (255, 0, 0))

                    distance_1 = depth_image[centery, min_x+5]
                    distance_2 = depth_image[centery, max_x-5]
                    distance_3 = depth_image[min_y+5, centerx]
                    distance_4 = depth_image[max_y-5, centerx]
                    distance_mm = depth_image[centery, centerx]

                    point1 = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(color_intrin, [min_x+5, centery], distance_1)
                    point2 = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(color_intrin, [max_x-5, centery], distance_2)
                    point3 = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(color_intrin, [centerx, min_y+5], distance_3)
                    point4 = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(color_intrin, [centerx, max_y-5], distance_4)
                    cnt_point = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(color_intrin, [centerx, centery], distance_mm)

                    wide_0 = int(90)
                    high_0 = int(140)

                    wide = int(math.sqrt(math.pow(point1[0] - point2[0], 2) + math.pow(point1[1] - point2[1], 2) +
                                         math.pow(point1[2] - point2[2], 2)))
                    high = int(math.sqrt(math.pow(point3[0] - point4[0], 2) + math.pow(point3[1] - point4[1], 2) +
                                         math.pow(point3[2] - point4[2], 2)))
                    if wide < high:
                        cv2.putText(im0, "{} mm".format(wide), (centerx, centery + 10), 0, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                        cv2.putText(im0, "{} mm".format(high), (centerx, centery + 30), 0, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    else:
                        cv2.putText(im0, "{} mm".format(wide), (centerx, centery + 10), 0, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                        cv2.putText(im0, "{} mm".format(high), (centerx, centery + 30), 0, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

                    if j == 5:
                        if wide < high:
                            wide_0 = wide
                            high_0 = high
                    cv2.circle(im0, (min_x, centery), 3, (255, 0, 0))
                    cv2.circle(im0, (max_x, centery), 3, (255, 0, 0))
                    cv2.circle(im0, (centerx, min_y), 3, (255, 0, 0))
                    cv2.circle(im0, (centerx, max_y), 3, (255, 0, 0))

                    """
                    Calculate the angle of the object respective to the camera
                    """
                    """
                    roll = round(asin(wide/wide_0)*180/pi, 1)

                    pitch = round(asin(high/high_0)*180/pi, 1)

                    cv2.putText(im0, "{} degree".format(roll), (centerx, centery + 50), 0, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    cv2.putText(im0, "{} degree".format(pitch), (centerx, centery + 70), 0, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    #print(center_point_updated)
                    """
                    #cv2.circle(im0, max_xy, 3, (255, 0, 0))
                    #annotator.draw.polygon(segments[j], outline=colors(c, True), width=3)

            # Stream results
            if view_img:
                if platform.system() == 'Linux' and p not in windows:
                    windows.append(p)
                    cv2.namedWindow(str(p), cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)  # allow window resize (Linux)
                    cv2.resizeWindow(str(p), im0.shape[1], im0.shape[0])
                cv2.imshow(str(p), im0)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):  # 1 millisecond
                    exit()

        # Print time (inference-only)
        LOGGER.info(f"{s}{'' if len(det) else '(no detections), '}{dt[1].dt * 1E3:.1f}ms")

    # Print results
    t = tuple(x.t / seen * 1E3 for x in dt)  # speeds per image
    LOGGER.info(f'seg:%.1fms seg, Speed: %.1fms pre-process, %.1fms inference, %.1fms NMS per image at shape {(1, 3, *imgsz)}' % t)

def parse_opt():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--weights', nargs='+', type=str, default=ROOT / 'yolov5s-seg.pt', help='model path(s)')
    parser.add_argument('--source', type=str, default=ROOT / 'data/images', help='file/dir/URL/glob/screen/0(webcam)')
    parser.add_argument('--data', type=str, default=ROOT / 'data/coco128.yaml', help='(optional) dataset.yaml path')
    parser.add_argument('--imgsz', '--img', '--img-size', nargs='+', type=int, default=[640], help='inference size h,w')
    parser.add_argument('--conf-thres', type=float, default=0.25, help='confidence threshold')
    parser.add_argument('--iou-thres', type=float, default=0.45, help='NMS IoU threshold')
    parser.add_argument('--max-det', type=int, default=1000, help='maximum detections per image')
    parser.add_argument('--device', default='', help='cuda device, i.e. 0 or 0,1,2,3 or cpu')
    parser.add_argument('--view-img', action='store_true', help='show results')
    parser.add_argument('--save-txt', action='store_true', help='save results to *.txt')
    parser.add_argument('--save-conf', action='store_true', help='save confidences in --save-txt labels')
    parser.add_argument('--save-crop', action='store_true', help='save cropped prediction boxes')
    parser.add_argument('--nosave', action='store_true', help='do not save images/videos')
    parser.add_argument('--classes', nargs='+', type=int, help='filter by class: --classes 0, or --classes 0 2 3')
    parser.add_argument('--agnostic-nms', action='store_true', help='class-agnostic NMS')
    parser.add_argument('--augment', action='store_true', help='augmented inference')
    parser.add_argument('--visualize', action='store_true', help='visualize features')
    parser.add_argument('--update', action='store_true', help='update all models')
    parser.add_argument('--project', default=ROOT / 'runs/predict-seg', help='save results to project/name')
    parser.add_argument('--name', default='exp', help='save results to project/name')
    parser.add_argument('--exist-ok', action='store_true', help='existing project/name ok, do not increment')
    parser.add_argument('--line-thickness', default=3, type=int, help='bounding box thickness (pixels)')
    parser.add_argument('--hide-labels', default=False, action='store_true', help='hide labels')
    parser.add_argument('--hide-conf', default=False, action='store_true', help='hide confidences')
    parser.add_argument('--half', action='store_true', help='use FP16 half-precision inference')
    parser.add_argument('--dnn', action='store_true', help='use OpenCV DNN for ONNX inference')
    parser.add_argument('--vid-stride', type=int, default=1, help='video frame-rate stride')
    parser.add_argument('--retina-masks', action='store_true', help='whether to plot masks in native resolution')
    opt = parser.parse_args()
    opt.imgsz *= 2 if len(opt.imgsz) == 1 else 1  # expand
    print_args(vars(opt))
    return opt


def main(opt):
    check_requirements(ROOT / 'requirements.txt', exclude=('tensorboard', 'thop'))
    run(**vars(opt))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    opt = parse_opt()
    main(opt)
```

And it gave me this error:

```
  File "/home/anthonia/Thesis/src/robot_project/yolov5-master/segment/test_seg.py", line 68, in get_frame_stream
    profile = pipe.start(cfg)
RuntimeError: xioctl(VIDIOC_S_FMT) failed, errno=16 Last Error: Device or resource busy
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The camera image window still appeared at first, but when it could detect the objects, it crashed and informed the device is busy even though I didn't use the realsense in another apps.
Is there the problem with threading **or** cross-platform problem between Ubuntu and Windows because when I running yolov5 segmentation code on Windows, it works?

Environment
YOLOv5  2023-10-3 Python-3.8.10 torch-2.1.0+cu118 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU, 3910MiB)
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Python version: 3.8.10 distributed with ROS Noetic

I tried to re-install the pyrealsense and librealsense package because the problem might be about the Kernel patch probelm. After I did that, the problem is still device or resource is busy.
However, the program from yolov5s.pt pack is still run. Is there any conflict between yolov5s-seg and librealsense?